# IE11 Объект не поддерживает свойство или метод "geocode"

Tags: yandex-maps-api

На сайте, при нажатии кнопочки появляется всплывающее окно, в котором отображается яндекс-карта. Во всех нормальных браузерах все работает, проблема только в IE версий 11 и ниже - в консоли выдает такую ошибку:
"Объект не поддерживает свойство или метод "geocode"".
При этом на других страница, где яндекс-карта отображается сразу (не во всплывающем окне) - все работает
Версия апи яндекс-карт 2.1

Кто может чего подсказать?

Comment: нужен адрес страницы, где воспроизводится проблема

Comment: эта проблема пока решена, она была следствием другой проблемы, не связанной с яндекс-картами

Comment: понятно, тогда лучше удалить вопрос)